# How to do set sessionflash if SQLSTATE[23000] foreign key cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have two tables:

[image: Picture]

When I try to delete `product_categories` it shows the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000] Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I want set session flash if it error?

Comment: can you pls share the code that you have written to delete the row?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to answer without the actual code that you have written but here is a generic answer based on what little you have shared. More detail is found at the Cake website at [this link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html#deleteall)

Assuming you are calling this from the Controller

```
if ($this->ProductCategory->deleteAll(array('conditions' => array('id' => $someId)) {
    // do something else - set success flash message
    $this->Session->setFlash('Something good.', 'default', array(), 'good');
} else {
    // error occurred
    $this->Session->setFlash('Something bad.', 'default', array(), 'bad');
}
```

You can also cascade deletes to child tables by setting an additional parameter in the delete statement above - this is also found at the same link. If you were to cascade deletes then the statement would look like below - notice the TRUE as the second parameter

```
if ($this->ProductCategory->deleteAll(array('conditions' => array('id' => $someId), true) {
    // do something else - set success flash message
    $this->Session->setFlash('Successfully deleted the Product Category', 'default');
} else {
    // error occurred
    $this->Session->setFlash('Cannot delete Product Category. Some Products are still using this Category.', 'default');
}
```

Also I would suggest that you do not enforce integrity constraints in the database - nothing really wrong with it but it will make your logic more complex.